# android- Parse string with fromHtml except <img> tag

Tags: android, html, string

is it possible to parse a string with html tags (like br, &nbsp, the accented letters, ..)  without parsing the image tag ? If yes , how can i do It?

Comment: no it's not a duplicate, with fromHtml i get a string fully parsed from Html, i want to parse all html tags except the img tag

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you are going to do with that parsed string.
If you need to display it in a TextView, then you could use

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(yourString, customImageGetter, null));
```

Where customImageGetter is your subclass of Html.ImageGetter which returns empty drawables in getDrawable(String source) method. Empty drawable could be an 1x1 transparent image.

Answer (score 0):

Define the html string in strings.xml and use this

```
<string name="about">
    <![CDATA[
    <html>
    <head></head>
    <body style="text-align:justify;">

    </body>
    </html>
    ]]>
```

tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.about)));

Comment: it's for messages, like chat, so i can't have a strings.xml about it

Comment: check out this sample from google
http://developer.android.com/samples/TextLinkify/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I guess this would work.
1. Initially, in the html tags instead of using `<img> </img>`, you will have to use `<image> </image>`

```
strTemp ="<h2>Title</h2><br><p>Description here</p> <image src='source here'></image>";
```

2.

```
Spanned sp = Html.fromHtml( strTemp );
```

3.

```
textView.setText(sp.toString().replace("image", "img"));
```